# How to prove by induction that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Im trying to prove
    $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = 1$

So far i've been making half-correct inductions proofs, and never had really good example of a good induction proof, so i feel like im getting stuck at weird place

I know that i have to first make an assumption, however in this case how do i know what that assumption is. I understand the function itself, i get it get infinitely close to 1 until i converges to 1, i assume i'll have to say something related to how $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=0$ . And of course show that it works for n=1, n=k and n=k+1, however im unable to somehow combine this together into a complete proof.

Sorry this question is probably asked alot, i tried searching around on induction alot and im honestly starting to feel lost.

Comment: Induction doesn't work here. Induction is good for finite sums, not infinite sums.

Comment: Induction can be used to prove a formula about the partial sums of the series, but it is not appropriate for finding its limit.

Answer (score 6):

**hint**

prove using induction that

$$(\forall N>0) \; \;\; \sum_{n=1}^N \frac {1}{2^n}=1-\frac {1}{2^N} $$

and then take it to the limit when $N $ becomes large.

Comment: So just to be sure, in this case N refers to when we've hit the limit of our infinity?

Comment: No. You never "hit your limit". The definition of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n$ is $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} a_n$. You use induction on $N$.

Answer (score 3):

Try writing out $s_n$ and $2s_n$ and look for a pattern.

Generally, for any infinite series you're going to have to work it out like this or similarly, induction will not work here for calculating the value.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't induction so if you explicity have to use induction, disregard it! Else it's a rather elegant way to solve the problem.

Let's call the sum $S$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}} = S$$

$$ S = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \ ... \ + \frac{1}{2^n}$$

Multiply both sides by the factor $\frac{1}{2}$, essentially shifting the entire series one step "forward".

$$\frac{1}{2}S = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{32} + \ ... \ + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$

Evaluate the equation $S - \frac{1}{2}S$, we can see that all terms cancel each other out except for the first term and the last term:

$$S - \frac{1}{2}S = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$
Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = 0$, the result is:

$$S - \frac{1}{2}S = \frac{1}{2} - 0$$
$$S = 1$$